# Why can't i change dictionary when for loop is working?

Tags: python, dictionary

So what I need is to add new key:value pairs or change existing, but my code is not working. What is wrong and how can I solve it?

What I want: create a dictionary, `key` is the symbol and the `value` is how many of this symbols in the list

My code:

```py
def f(data: list):
    characters = dict()
    for i in data:
        if i in characters:
            characters[i] += 1
        elif i not in data:
            characters[i] = 1
    return characters
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of an image.

Comment: Ok but see what happens? That is not understandable! How can i post my code in normal way?

Comment: Please use the code markup for the code.  See my answer.

Comment: As @biomiker said, use code markup. The simplest way would be to paste your code in, highlight said code, then click the `{}` button.

Comment: The problem simply was the line `elif i not in data:`. I guess that was a typo. You probably wanted to write `... not in characters:` because of course the element was taken out of the list `data` and so the second branch will never be executed, this is why your dictionary always is empty. But of course, you can simply replace it by an `else:` statement, because there is no third option anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post your code instead of a screenshot.  But, your code is guaranteed to return an empty dictionary regardless of your input.  Both of your conditions will always evaluate to false.  I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
if i in characters:
   characters[i] += 1
else:
   characters[i] = 1
```

Comment: Ok i'll post my code instead of a screenshot next time. And your solution worked! but IDK why, can you explain it?    Edit: Never mind i just figured it out, thank you for answer!

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer if it worked for you.  The bug in your code was that the second conditional never gets executed because you are checking that the character is not in your original data source (which of course it always will be).  You probably meant to check if it was not in your output dict "characters".  But that's not necessary explicitly, just using the else is sufficient because your first conditional tests if the character is in your output dict "characters".

Answer (score 0):

Change your `elif i not in data:` line to `else:` or `elif i not in characters:`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified if you can use `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def f(data):
    characters = defaultdict(int)
    for i in data:
        characters[i] += 1
    return characters
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import Counter

characters = Counter(Data)
```

The function `Counter()` from `collections` is exactly what you need.